# How to prevent Java applications from creating tray icon?

Tags: unity, java, icons, indicator, system-tray

With Ubuntu 13.04 the possibility to whitelist (and consequentely blacklist) certain applications from creating a tray icon is gone. Since then the tray icons of Java applications and Wine icons are hardcoded and always visible.

Although there are certain ppas, that provide a unity patch by giving back the systray.whitelist (not for 14.04 though, yet) I'd like to know if there are other ways to hide the tray-icons of java apps (e.g. JDownloader)

I know that there's a way in doing so for qt-applications by implementing apparmor-profiles that deny read access to the sni-qt package (e.g. for Skype, or Spotify)

Is there a way to implement apparmor profiles or something similar for Java applications and/or Wine applications?

thanks

Comment: You could access their icons, and change them to be transparent and small, so it takes up almost no space and is invisible?

Comment: Good idea, but no. The 16x16 place seems to be reserved for java applications. By changing to a invisible 1px svg, one gets still a 16x16 not transparent icon

Comment: OK, thats a shame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Sneetshers answer is perfect I discovered a simpler (and obvious) solution. This approach works with JDownloader, but should also work with all other Java programs.

Just remove the logo `rm ~/.jdownloader/jd/img/logo/jd_logo_128_128.png` and afterwards create a invalid png icon with `touch ~/.jdownloader/jd/img/logo/jd_logo_128_128.png`

Using this approach, one can still use the TrayIcon plugin (useful for minimizing to tray) without the ugly java icon

Answer (score 2):

### For Java Apps:

- Actually for JDownloader case, It's a modular design. Tray icon comes as a plugin that can be disabled from:

  JDownloader → Addons → Addon Manager → Extensions → Uncheck *Activate* box for *JD Light Tray*
- For Java applications general case, It is possible to use Java security manager by writing a custom policy rules.

  1. Create `java.policy` file in `~/.jdownloader` contains:

     ```
     grant codeBase "file:/home/user/.jdownloader/-" {

     // full access
     //    permission java.security.AllPermission;

     // AWTPermission full or only selected elements from it
     //    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "*";

         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessEventQueue";
     //    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessSystemTray";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "createRobot";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "fullScreenExclusive";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "listenToAllAWTEvents";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "readDisplayPixels";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "replaceKeyboardFocusManager";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setAppletStub";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setWindowAlwaysOnTop";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "toolkitModality";
         permission java.awt.AWTPermission "watchMousePointer";

     // Added by try and learn
         permission java.io.FilePermission "/-", "read,write,delete";
         permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
         permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control";
         permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
         permission java.net.NetPermission "*";
         permission java.security.SecurityPermission "*";
         permission javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission "*";
         permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "connect,resolve";
         permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "*";
     };
     ```
  2. Modify `jdownloader` launch script to use custom policy

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/bin/jdownloader
     ```

     Add: `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=java.policy` to java command call:

     ```
     exec java ${JAVA_OPTIONS}  -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=java.policy -jar JDownloader.jar $*
     ```

These are the minimum rules that allowed me to launch jdownloader. You may need to add more permissions. Because there is no `deny` option you have to write all needed `grant` rules.

**References:**

- [`java.awt`: Class SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html#getSystemTray%28%29)
- [`java.awt`: Class AWTPermission](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/AWTPermission.html)
- [`java.security`: Class BasicPermission](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/BasicPermission.html)

  See *Direct Known Subclasses* if you want to write a general template that grant `AllPermission` except `accessSystemTray`. So you can use it for all remaining java apps.

BTW, try to comment one of the rules by adding `//` to the beginning of line; So you can see how the error of denied permissions looks like. It tells you which permission you should to add. Also notice that I have used many `-` & `*` trying to extend rules as I'm looking for a quick solution (default was `AllPermission` anyway) and I'm not looking to jail the application.

Here is a template to start with, trying to grant all possible permissions:

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/user/.jdownloader/-" {

//    permission java.security.AllPermission;

//    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "*";

    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessEventQueue";
//    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessSystemTray";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "createRobot";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "fullScreenExclusive";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "listenToAllAWTEvents";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "readDisplayPixels";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "replaceKeyboardFocusManager";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setAppletStub";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setWindowAlwaysOnTop";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "toolkitModality";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "watchMousePointer";


    permission javax.sound.sampled.AudioPermission "*";
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "*";
//    permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.DelegationPermission "";
    permission javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission "*";
    permission java.nio.file.LinkPermission "hard";
    permission java.nio.file.LinkPermission "symbolic";
    permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control";
//    permission java.lang.management.ManagementPermission "*";
    permission javax.management.MBeanServerPermission "*";
    permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "*";
    permission java.net.NetPermission "*";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "*";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
    permission java.security.SecurityPermission "*";
    permission java.io.SerializablePermission "*";
    permission java.sql.SQLPermission "*";
    permission javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission "*";
    permission javax.management.remote.SubjectDelegationPermission "*";
    permission javax.xml.ws.WebServicePermission "*";
//    permission  "*";

    permission java.io.FilePermission "/-", "read,write,execute,delete,readlink";
    permission javax.management.MBeanPermission "*", "*";
//    permission javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission "", "read";
    permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission "*", "initiate,accept";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "accept,connect,listen,resolve";
    permission java.net.URLPermission "*";
};
```

**Note**:

Java Policy Tools is a GUI tool to edit policy files. It make it more easy t find out all available options from drop box. It should be already install with Java package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I see no obvious better solutions, it's possible that this will help:

You could get rid of the tray alltogether!

- either disable it, if possible
- or replace the whole panel by some other that you can configure manually, just not adding a tray element. (I like `xfce4-panel` for this kind of things)

If you would miss tray-based features now, most should be replacable case by case somehow, like a scrip showing desktop notifications on some events.

Comment: Ok thanks, but this is obviously not what I wanted. I like the unity-tray, I just dislike some of the tray-icons

Comment: Yes, that was more of a shot in the dark, in terms of knowing your underlying usecase. For an 'appliance'-style machine, runing one fixed application, plus the desktop bar for basic menus only. the method would even work :)  [But I remember I have once seen a message of some program refusing to start with no panel... ]

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the applications that use a tray icon to be able to make use of it in Ubuntu 14.04, you can use a PPA that comes with Unity patched to re-enable the systray whitelist. To do this, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, restart Unity by pressing ALT + F2 and entering "unity" or by logging out. The PPA now automatically whitelists all applications so there's no need to manually whitelist individual apps to be able to use the systray.

**Reverting the changes**

If you want to revert the changes and go back to the default Unity packages from the Ubuntu repositories, use the commands below to purge the Unity systray whitelist PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
```

From http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Stak Exchange! Please, include essential part of link in your answer to prevent breaking post after link dies.

Comment: That's a global whitelist, which means that all programs are whitelisted. Blacklisting programs (like wine and Java programs) ist the complete opposite and does not work with this version of unity neither